Usual way of defining Reflection in Plane
We shall call a set $P(a,t)$ a plane in $\hat{\mathbb{R}^n}$(Extended plane) if it is of the form $P(a,t)=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n: (x.a)=t\}\cup \{\infty\},$ where $a\in\mathbb{R}^n$,$a\ne 0,(x.a)$ usual scalar product and $t$ real . The reflection $\phi$ in $P(a,t)$ is defined in the usual way that is $\phi(x)=x+\lambda a$ where the real parameter $\lambda$ is chosen so that $\frac
{1}{2}(x+\phi(x))$ is on $P(a,t).$
My Question is , why it's the usual way to define reflection in plane ? In $\mathbb{R}^2$ if we take $a=(1,0)$ then it's clear . In general intuition is not coming in my mind.

In general, a (hyper)plane $P$ in $n$-space has a normal vector (in your language, the vector $a$ serves this role) and an offset from the origin (i.e., we insist that $x \cdot a = t$ rather than $x \cdot a = 0$, which wou;d give a plane through the origin).
Now think about "reflection through P", keeping in mind the case where $P$ is a line in the cartesian plane, or a 2D plane in 3-space. If you have some point $x$, its reflection $x'$ through $P$ will be on the "other side" of $P$, but not just any point $x'$ on the other side will suffice. The key ideas are that that

the line from $x$ to $x'$ should be a multiple of the normal vector (to see your reflection in a pool of water, you have to look straight down!), and

the distance from $x$ to $P$ should be the same as the distance from $x'$ to $P$.


That second condition can be expressed by saying that the midpoint of the segment from $x$ to $x'$ should be a point of $P$. And that's what your "the real parameter $\lambda$ is chosen..." phrase says!
Post-comment addition
To explain the first point, consider (in the 2D case) a ray $r$ from $x$ towards the point $u \in P$ that's closest to $x$, let's say at distance $h$.

That ray meets the "plane" (a line in this case) at a 90-degree angle. For if we consider a circle of radius $h$ around $x$, then (a) $u$ lies on that circle, and (b) the entire circle lies on one side of $P$. (If some point $q$ of  the circle were on the other side of $P$, then the segment from $x$ to $q$ would meet $P$ at some point $v$ between $x$ and $q$, and $v$ would be closer to $x$ than $u$.) As a consequence of these, we see that the plane/line is tangent to the circle, so the normal to the plane/line is in fact the normal to the circle at $u$, which is exactly the ray from $u$ to $x$.

The reflection of $x$ through the plane/line, i.e., $x'$, must lie on the ray from $x$ through $u$ because of the "look at yourself in a pool of water" argument.



I don't understand your first point why line should be multiple of normal  vector?

See post-comment addition. If you're not happy with that, perhaps you can explain to me what you think "the reflection of $x$ in the plane $P$" means in words, so that I can better understand where we're failing to connect on this.
